# Allow directory listing for subdirectories only

Tags: iis7, directory-listing

I am using webspace hosted on IIS 7.5 (according to phpinfo() ). Currently, I am enabling directory listings for a directory and all its subdirectories by placing a web.config like

```
<location path=".">
    <system.webServer>
      <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

in it. Is there a way to disable the directory listing in the directory itself but enable it for all its subdirectories without placing a web.config in each subdirectory or listing all subdirectories here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this works in a similar way to Apache, then you could simply create an index.php file (or whatever your directory index file is) in the directory that you don't want to see a directory listing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes if you `allowOverride` and then add a new web.config file in the folder you want to disable.

So in your parent folder web.config should look like this.

```
<configuration>
   <location path="." allowOverride="True">
      <system.webServer>
         <directoryBrowse enabled="True" />
      </system.webServer>
   </location>
<configuration>
```

In the folders you want to disable directory browse the web.config should look like this.

```
<configuration>
   <location path=".">
      <system.webServer>
         <directoryBrowse enabled="False" />
      </system.webServer>
   </location>
<configuration>
```

For more info check this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).